# .Prototype. does not work with eventListener

Tags: javascript, events, prototype

I want to make my code in **Prototype style** coding. But I ran into difficulties - for some reasons `onclick` function does not want to run.

Can someone to explain me where my problem is?

```js
    function Voter(options) {
      this.elem = options.elem;
      this.voteElem = this.elem.querySelector('.vote');
    }

    Voter.prototype.onmousedown = function() { 
        return false;
    };

    Voter.prototype.onclick = function(event) { // this is my problem
      if (this.elem.closest('.down')) {
        this.voteDecrease();

      } else if (this.elem.closest('.up')) {
        this.voteIncrease();
      }
    };

    Voter.prototype.voteDecrease = function() {
      this.voteElem.innerHTML = +this.voteElem.innerHTML - 1;
      console.log(this.voteElem);
    }

    Voter.prototype.voteIncrease = function() {
      this.voteElem.innerHTML = +this.voteElem.innerHTML + 1;
    }

    Voter.prototype.setVote = function(vote, voteElem) {
        this.voteElem.innerHTML = +vote;
      };

    var voter = new Voter({
      elem: document.getElementById('voter')
    });

    voter.setVote(1);
    voter.onclick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .down, .up {
      color:  blue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="voter" class="voter">
    <span class="down">—</span>
    <span class="vote">0</span>
    <span class="up">+</span>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It really doesn't seem like a good idea to hook eventListeners to the prototype chain

Comment: @SterlingArcher ok, maybe we can put listener into the Constructor `Voter`?

Comment: You dont listen to any `onclick` event.

Comment: I'm trying to get some extra input, but I think that would be better. Something about hooking the chain to an event listener doesn't feel right to me

Comment: @JonasW. why you think so?

Comment: Cause you dont do anything with `this.elem.onclick` ?

Comment: you haven't called `addEventListener`.

Comment: @JonasW. I do not understand... I have bind `this.elem.onclick` to `voter` by prototype. This eventListener must handler it...

Comment: @sviat no. Voter does not inherit a dom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `closest`function gets the ancestor, not your siblings.
- You need to bind the `onclick` event to your `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling`.
- Use `this.voteElem` to get your siblings.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function Voter(options) {
  this.elem = options.elem;
  this.voteElem = this.elem.querySelector('.vote');
}

Voter.prototype.onmousedown = function() {
  return false;
};

Voter.prototype.onclick = function(event) {
  var self = this;
  
  this.voteElem.previousElementSibling.onclick = function() {
    self.voteDecrease();
  };

  this.voteElem.nextElementSibling.onclick = function() {
    self.voteIncrease();
  };
};

Voter.prototype.voteDecrease = function() {
  this.voteElem.innerHTML = +this.voteElem.innerHTML - 1;
}

Voter.prototype.voteIncrease = function() {
  this.voteElem.innerHTML = +this.voteElem.innerHTML + 1;
}

Voter.prototype.setVote = function(vote, voteElem) {
  this.voteElem.innerHTML = +vote;
};

var voter = new Voter({
  elem: document.getElementById('voter')
});

voter.setVote(1);
voter.onclick();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    .down,
    .up {
      color: blue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="voter" class="voter">
    <span class="down" id='down'>—</span>
    <span class="vote">0</span>
    <span class="up" id='up'>+</span>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

See? your prototype logic is working now.

## Resources

- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/previousElementSibling)
- [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to listen for the click events of the closest up/down, one could change the constructor to:

```
function Voter(options) {
  this.elem = options.elem;
  this.voteElem = this.elem.querySelector('.vote');

  this.elem.closest(".up").onclick = () => this.voteIncrease();
  this.elem.closest(".down").onclick = () => this.voteDecrease();
}
```

For shure you can add that into an extra method, but i dont see a need for that.

Comment: Okay, thanks! But purely theoretically, how could we do this through prototypes? Thank you

Comment: @sviat you dont want that. That would be very hacky

Comment: Using your function I got an Error - `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` :( on `this.elem.closest(".up").onclick`

Comment: @sviat thats another thing. Using `closest` will not work here as down is not an ancestor of vote thats why it isnt foumd

Comment: Using the conditions like `this.elem.tagName == (".up")` also does not help... :(

If you can, give me one more idea, please )

Comment: @sviat hint: just do it the same way you did with `.vote` ;) if that doenst help [click here](http://jsbin.com/tupucezepa/edit?output)